# Multi-Tier SharePoint Deployment - Read-only Web Servers

Tags: deployment, architecture, public-website

Is it possible to have the following deployment architecture for hosting SharePoint internet websites? If yes, how can I make the front-end web servers as read-only while allowing content modifications on a server behind DMZ through internal network?

Tier-1 (DMZ):

### 2 x Front-end Web Servers in read-only mode (No content modifications allowed via internet).

Tier-2:
1 x Back-end Web Server where content managers update and publish content via internal network.

### 1 x Application Server with Central Administration + Indexing Service

Tier-3:
2 x Clustered Database Servers

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario you should setup 2 different Farms. One in the DMZ and one internal for authoring.
Now you can use the SharePoint built-in ["Content Deployment"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721058%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to publish content from the authoring farm to your internet farm.